# MySQL Query Date Errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have this query that indexes my images and orders them by popularity but I cant make the user to choose the interval cause there's something wrong with the query:

```
switch($Data['data']){
    case 'daily':$QueryDate='=CURDATE()';break;
    case 'weekly':$QueryDate=' BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS) AND NOW()';break;
    case 'monthly':$QueryDate='>CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAYS';break;
    default: Core::redirect('image/browse/daily/1');break;
}
$IMGDB = new Database('images');
$query = "SELECT *, (derived.`likes` * 2 + derived.`views`) as `popularity` from 
 (SELECT *, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE `like`=I.id AND `date`".$QueryDate.") AS `likes`, 
  (SELECT SUM(`views`) FROM `views` WHERE `id`=I.id AND `date`".$QueryDate.") AS `views`
  FROM images AS I
 ) AS derived
where 1 ORDER BY `popularity` DESC ";
```

Only the daily case works.

Here is the error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;..... to use near 'DAYS) AND NOW()) AS likes, (SELECT SUM(views) FROM views WHERE id= I.id A

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @TarynEast SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;..... to use near 'DAYS) AND NOW()) AS `likes`, (SELECT SUM(`views`) FROM `views` WHERE `id`= I.id A'

Comment: It's `INTERVAL 7 DAY`, not `DAYS`.

Comment: @Sammitch create an answer so I could choose it as solution.

Comment: instead of `>CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAY`, you might want to use `>CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`, just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for specifying an interval of days uses the `DAY` keyword. You've used `DAYS` in:

```
BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAYS) AND NOW()
```

and:

```
> CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAYS
```